why did this way to "repair" the grub after installing Windows worked?
I've read this answer here on how to repair the grub.
In my case  though, I accessed to the boot loader and put Ubuntu as first option to load. Then, Ubuntu prompts me to either use Windows or Ubuntu if I want to (wouldn't work in reverse).
Is the workaround only for Windows being the primary system ?

You link is to the very old BIOS/MBR configuration. With BIOS only one boot loader can be MBR.  With UEFI there are two places to set order as UEFI can have multiple systems in the one ESP - efi system partition. One is UEFI default, Windows or Ubuntu/grub and then in grub for preferred choice. Windows will not boot other installs other than another install of Windows without third party tools that are not recommended. So having grub as default is recommended. But grub only boots working Windows, so sometimes you have to use UEFI to directly boot Windows to fix it.

what is BIOS, MBR, UEFI in practical terms @oldfred?

UEFI is replacement for old BIOS. Microsoft has equired vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012. MBR refers to both the partitioning and that it has a first sector for both boot code & list of 4 primary partitions. Gpt keeps a MBR, only so very old partitioning tools do not see gpt & erase drive. BIOS - Basic Input/Output System http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS & https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

thanks for explaining to me @oldfred, that's useful.
